# Wrap text to right, inside a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through some sites for design inspirations and found a menu quite a while ago and took inspiration from it.

It goes as follows when I click on the products in black background, the menu items should display from left. I have achieved the animation part using GSAP. I want the menu items to wrap on to the rounded edges of the red circle and center of the visible red area. The problem is the menu items are not being calculated from the center of the circle but are being positioned equally along the edges of the circle. Is there a dynamic way to calculate it or should I place them by static margins and paddings. And as you can see if the menu item has two or more words it should wrap and align itself to the center of itself. I have used a break just to achieve the layout.

Can someone point me in the right direction and help me reach my destination in this.  Cheers.

Here is the inspirational image: https://i.ibb.co/QJFmsXJ/Untitled.png

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $mainmenu = $('.menu');
  var $menuItemsWrap = $(".sub-menu");
  var $MenuItems = $(".sub-menu li");

  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu-dummy').css({
      "display": "block",
      "z-index": "5"
    });
    $('.menu').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    TweenMax.to($menuItemsWrap, 0.6, {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      ease: Power1.easeIn
    });
    TweenMax.staggerTo($MenuItems, 0.5, {
      x: 80,
      opacity: 1,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      delay: 0.6
    }, 0.1);

  });
  $('.menu-dummy').click(function() {
    $('.menu-dummy').css({
      "display": "none",
    });
    $('.menu').css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    TweenMax.staggerTo($MenuItems, 0.5, {
      x: -80,
      autoAlpha: 1,
      ease: Power1.easeOut
    }, 0.05);
    TweenMax.to($menuItemsWrap, 0.6, {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      ease: Power1.easeIn,
      delay: 1
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bubble-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: grey;
}

.menu.menu-style1 {
  z-index: 4;
}

.menu.menu-style1,
.menu-dummy.menu-style1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menu-wrap {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-wrap h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(25px);
}

.menu-wrap i {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 3;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sub-menu li {
  transform: translate(-80px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="bubble-menu">
  <div class="menu menu-style1">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <h3>Products</h3>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-dummy menu-style1">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <h3>Products</h3>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu1 very big</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu4 big</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</div>
```

Here is the codepen [Link](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/MWWBrbx)

Comment: Can you give a link to the original inspiration?

Comment: The red circle is not circle in the backend side, it is only `width` and `height`, so texts will just go within the circle's rectangular boundaries

Comment: @Sarreph I just have an image of it. I could share if you want.

Comment: see this pic https://ibb.co/yYVfhYr

Comment: @Shizukura Can we do something like getting the outer width of the red circle or something like that.

Comment: It would definitely help visualize the problem if you included it as a link in the question :)

Comment: sure thing just a min

Comment: @Sarreph Please check the image

Comment: related to get some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54960845/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ill bang my head around it and will update you. ;-p

Comment: @MohammedWahedKhan added my answer below with codepen link, I used each loop for li element. Hope this will solve your problem or give you some logic about how we can achieve this.

Comment: @Priyanka Im checking on it. ( :-) }

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something good and new, great job! :)

Here is something I tried with your code, I tried to achieve this requirement by js. Please have look into the codepen link provided here. Hope will it will help you. while you click there is still some jump feels in animation, but you can play with it later to resolve that. I just want to show you the logic behind it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var $mainmenu = $('.menu');
  var $menuItemsWrap = $(".sub-menu");
  var $MenuItems = $(".sub-menu li");

  $('.menu').click(function () {
    $('.menu-dummy').css({"display": "block", "z-index": "5"});
    $('.menu').css({"display": "none"});
    TweenMax.to($menuItemsWrap, 0.6, {width: 400,height: 400,ease: Power1.easeIn });
    var xpositionforfirst = 80;
    $(".sub-menu ul.first li").each(function(i) {
        var item = $(this);
        console.log(item);
        TweenMax.staggerTo(item, 0.5, { x: xpositionforfirst, opacity: 1, ease: Power1.easeOut, delay: 0.6 }, 0.1);
      xpositionforfirst = xpositionforfirst + 30;
    });
    var xpositionforsecond = 140;
    $(".sub-menu ul.second li").each(function(i) {
        var item = $(this);
        console.log(item);
        TweenMax.staggerTo(item, 0.5, { x: xpositionforsecond, opacity: 1, ease: Power1.easeOut, delay: 0.6 }, 0.1);
      xpositionforsecond = xpositionforsecond - 30;
    });   
  });
  $('.menu-dummy').click(function () {
    $('.menu-dummy').css({"display": "none",});
     $('.menu').css({"display": "block"});
    TweenMax.staggerTo($MenuItems, 0.5, { x: -80, autoAlpha: 1, ease: Power1.easeOut }, 0.05);
    TweenMax.to($menuItemsWrap, 0.6, {width: 0,height: 0,ease: Power1.easeIn, delay: 1 });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/yLLxqvz

Comment: I can see that the script is working 100% correctly but it is conflicting with the delay in the tweening will you please have a look on that. One more thing what are the static values that are being passed in the `xpositionforfirst` and `xpositionforsecond`.

Comment: I guess there is no other option rather than passing some static value.  We can't calculate the block width if it's border-radius is 50%

Comment: Then I guess there is no point in making a part it dynamic if it runs on static values.